# running C code will appear problems in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Excuse me, I'm not a professional programmer. I always write C++ code. Recently, when I run C code, I find a problem and can't get results successfully. The console tells me that `Parameter format not correct`. And I don't know how to solve it. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

The console outputs it when the C code runs:

```
PS E:\realGasCal20230612> chcp 65001  "e:\realGasCal20230612\test.c"
Parameter format not correct
```

I find that when I click "run this file", I can't get the result what I want. So I have to input the running command in the console. I write it and it can run successfully! But I also don't know why I can't run C code by clicking the button of "running this file".

The console outputs it when the C code runs:

```
PS E:\realGasCal20230612> if ($?) {g++ test.c -o test } ; if ($?) {.\test}                         
hello world!
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: If you type `chcp /?` in PowerShell, it'll tell you the correct syntax for that command. It accepts a single optional argument. You gave it two arguments. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, but this problem has nothing to do with C programming.

Comment: Regarding _"why I can't run C code by clicking the button of "running this file""_, that is because C code is not executable. It must be compiled into executable form using a C compiler. The operating system cannot natively execute C code. Given that you are asking this question in this way, I am seriously doubting the claim that you _"always write C++ code"_. C++ also requires a compiler. It's kinda the first thing you learn when you start using either of these languages.